# Hot Code Replace can't work with spring-boot-starter-validation in VSCode

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hot-code-replace

I have a Spring Boot project with a model class below:

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Item {
    @NotNull
    public int id;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    public String email;
}
```

Here is my API's action:

```java
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Item> createItem(@Valid @RequestBody Item item) {
    try {
        Item createdItem = new Item();

        URI createdUri = URI.create("/api/Home/999");
        return ResponseEntity.created(createdUri).body(createdItem);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().build();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the [Hot Code Replace](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/java/hot-code-replacement-for-java-comes-to-visual-studio-code/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686) feature with input validation in Spring Boot.  Here is what I found. When I changed the validation annotation in the model class, the [Hot Code Replace](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/java/hot-code-replacement-for-java-comes-to-visual-studio-code/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686) is not working. I have to restart my app to take effect. Is there any way to support this?